# blogdown: 'system3' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

Tags: r, web, windows-10, hugo, blogdown

On `Windows 10`, I am getting the following error with `blogdown::new_site()` function:

> Hugo has been installed to "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\0.89.4".
> You are recommended to set options(blogdown.hugo.version = "0.89.4")
> in the .Rprofile file in your website project. See the blogdown book
> for more info on .Rprofile:
> https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html
>
> Error: 'system3' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

I'm wondering what am I missing here? Any hints.

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xfun_0.28

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2 tools_4.1.2    blogdown_1.6.5 pacman_0.5.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to install the dev version of **blogdown** without installing the dev version of **xfun** at the same time, since the latter is required ([as specified in DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/3d75c35b4c9991c1517924dc11b730cf954637c6/DESCRIPTION#L67)). Per [installation instruction in README](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown#installation), this is how you install the dev version of **blogdown**:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

And the dev version of **xfun** should be installed automatically (note that you will need RTools).

Comment: **xfun**  is already installed. However, even after installing the dev version of `blogdown`, getting the same error:  `| Installing Hugo
The latest Hugo version is v0.89.4
trying URL 'https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.89.4/hugo_extended_0.89.4_Windows-64bit.zip'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 16437214 bytes (15.7 MB)
downloaded 15.7 MB
`

Comment: `Hugo has been installed to "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\0.89.4". You are recommended to set options(blogdown.hugo.version = "0.89.4") in the .Rprofile file in your website project. See the blogdown book for more info on .Rprofile: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html
Error: 'system3' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'`

Comment: I mean when you `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`, it should automatically do `remotes::install_github('yihui/xfun')`. I don't know why it didn't. You can install the dev version of **xfun** manually.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I get the exact same error trying to following the TL;DR section of [this blog](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2020-12-new-year-new-blogdown/#tldr) and that is after explicitly updating the `xfun` package.  Here is the entire code segment I am trying to run:

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/blogdown")
usethis::create_project()
blogdown::new_site(theme = "wowchemy/starter-academic")
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
09:14:26  > blogdown::new_site(theme = "wowchemy/starter-academic")
― Creating your new site
| Installing Hugo
The latest Hugo version is v0.90.1
trying URL 'https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.90.1/hugo_extended_0.90.1_macOS-ARM64.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 16102460 bytes (15.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 15.4 MB

Hugo has been installed to "/Users/rogerbos/Library/Application Support/Hugo/0.90.1". 
Error: 'system3' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'
09:14:26  >
```

and here is my sessionInfo():

```
9:14:26  > sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  utils     stats     graphics  grDevices methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] alphavantager_0.1.2 googlesheets4_1.0.0 googledrive_2.0.0  
 [4] clipr_0.7.1         jsonlite_1.7.2      stringi_1.7.6      
 [7] dtplyr_1.1.0        data.table_1.14.2   dplyr_1.0.7        
[10] plyr_1.8.6          testthat_3.1.0      lubridate_1.8.0    
[13] timeDate_3043.102   sendmailR_1.2-1     rmarkdown_2.11     
[16] devtools_2.4.2      usethis_2.1.3       xts_0.12.1         
[19] zoo_1.8-9           MASS_7.3-54         fortunes_1.5-4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        lattice_0.20-45   prettyunits_1.1.1
 [4] ps_1.6.0          assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_2.0.2  
 [7] digest_0.6.29     utf8_1.2.2        R6_2.5.1         
[10] cellranger_1.1.0  evaluate_0.14     blogdown_1.6.5   
[13] httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.6.4      rlang_0.4.12     
[16] curl_4.3.2        rstudioapi_0.13   callr_3.7.0      
[19] desc_1.4.0        compiler_4.1.2    xfun_0.28        
[22] pkgconfig_2.0.3   askpass_1.1       base64enc_0.1-3  
[25] pkgbuild_1.2.0    htmltools_0.5.2   openssl_1.4.5    
[28] tidyselect_1.1.1  tibble_3.1.5      bookdown_0.24    
[31] fansi_0.5.0       crayon_1.4.2      withr_2.4.2      
[34] rappdirs_0.3.3    grid_4.1.2        lifecycle_1.0.1  
[37] DBI_1.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    cli_3.1.0        
[40] cachem_1.0.6      fs_1.5.0          remotes_2.4.1    
[43] ellipsis_0.3.2    vctrs_0.3.8       generics_0.1.1   
[46] tools_4.1.2       glue_1.5.1        purrr_0.3.4      
[49] processx_3.5.2    pkgload_1.2.3     fastmap_1.1.0    
[52] gargle_1.2.0      sessioninfo_1.2.1 memoise_2.0.0    
[55] knitr_1.36
```